# Is my ccminer working?

Tags: gpu-mining, ccminer

Got `ccminer` to work on my Acer Predator Laptop w/ 1060 Nvidia GeForce 
GTX. I'm seeing a lot of `retry` messages in the miner log and I'm unable to tell if it's working.

When I input my address into `monerohash.com` it says "Not found". Not sure if that's because I've only been mining for about an hour. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

```
ccminer -o stratum+tcp://monerohash.com:3333 -u <address removed> -p x
*** ccminer-cryptonight for nVidia GPUs by tsiv ***
based on ccMiner by Christian Buchner and Christian H.
based on cpuminer-multi by LucasJones
based on pooler-cpuminer 2.3.2 (c) 2010 Jeff Garzik, 2012 pooler
BTC donation address: 1JHDKp59t1RhHFXsTw2UQpR3F9BBz3R3cs
DRK donation address: XrHp267JNTVdw5P3dsBpqYfgTpWnzoESPQ
JPC donation address: Jb9hFeBgakCXvM5u27rTZoYR9j13JGmuc2
VTC donation address: VwYsZFPb6KMeWuP4voiS9H1kqxcU9kGbsw
XMR donation address: 
(man these are long... single address, split on two lines)
42uasNqYPnSaG3TwRtTeVbQ4aRY3n9jY6VXX3mfgerWt4ohDQLVaBPv3cYGKDXasTUVuLvhxetcuS16ynt85czQ48mbSrWX
[2018-01-01 19:18:12] Using JSON-RPC 2.0
[2018-01-01 19:18:12] 1 miner threads started, using 'cryptonight' algorithm.
[2018-01-01 19:18:12] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060 (10 SMX), using 40 blocks of 8 threads
[2018-01-01 19:18:12] Starting Stratum on stratum+tcp://monerohash.com:3333
[2018-01-01 19:18:12] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:18:13] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 314.56 H/s
[2018-01-01 19:18:42] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:18:43] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 179.07 H/s
[2018-01-01 19:19:12] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:19:12] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 162.70 H/s
[2018-01-01 19:19:43] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:19:44] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 172.14 H/s
[2018-01-01 19:20:13] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:20:15] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 168.19 H/s
[2018-01-01 19:20:43] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:20:45] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 170.79 H/s
[2018-01-01 19:21:14] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:21:14] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 160.07 H/s
[2018-01-01 19:21:44] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:21:45] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 169.88 H/s
[2018-01-01 19:22:14] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:22:14] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 162.26 H/s
[2018-01-01 19:22:45] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:22:46] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 173.16 H/s
[2018-01-01 19:23:15] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 262.47 H/s
[2018-01-01 19:23:15] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:23:45] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 422.18 H/s
[2018-01-01 19:23:45] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:24:16] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 421.60 H/s
[2018-01-01 19:24:16] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:24:46] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:24:46] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 426.30 H/s
[2018-01-01 19:25:16] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:25:17] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 421.94 H/s
[2018-01-01 19:25:46] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:25:47] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 414.55 H/s
[2018-01-01 19:26:17] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:26:17] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 425.48 H/s
[2018-01-01 19:26:47] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 414.14 H/s
[2018-01-01 19:26:47] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:27:17] ...retry after 30 seconds
[2018-01-01 19:27:18] GPU #0: GeForce GTX 1060, 409.28 H/s
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have your wallet ID/payment address after `-u` .. if that wasn't redacted for this post then that may be your issue.  You can have a look at my pool which has a configuration utility that might help:

**Gulf Coast Mining**
https://mon.gulfcoastmining.com

Comment: address was redacted. the link doesnt appear to be working?

Comment: Ok on the address ... as per "the link" if you mean my pool they are up and running correctly. Just confirmed on my mobile to make sure. You may have larger network issues which might explain your difficulties. We also have a Vert pool if you care just to check DNS: https://vtc2.gulfcoastmining.com